# Chrome no confia en certificado wildcard autofirmado

Tags: ssl, https, chrome

Necesitamos crear un certificado autofirmado tipo wildcard para varias aplicaciones internas:

***.dominio.int**

Que autorice aplicaciones tipo:

**test1.dominio.int**, **test2.dominio.int**

Estando importado en el almacen local de autoridades en las que se confia, funciona bien. En IE y Firefox no da problemas, pero en chrome si: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Creando el cert con lo nombres DNS altenativos para cada aplicacion, funciona.

Pero si en un futuro creamos una nueva aplicacion **test3.dominio.int** nuestro certificado no va a funcionar para esta nueva app.

Sabeis alguna solucion ?

Gracias, saludos

Comment: Probaste con el wildcard en el SAN? Te dejo este link que creo que trata tu tema. https://grokify.github.io/security/wildcard-subject-alternative-name-ssl-tls-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una serie de pasos que te solucionarán el problema.

## Crear certificado wildcard  SSL autofirmado válido

Configurar archivo openssl.cnf ir a la ruta

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\conf\
```

abrir archivo openssl.cnf

Dentro del archivo descomentar y modificar la variable req_extensions

```
req_extensions = req_ext
```

Añadir al final del archivo

```
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = dominio
DNS.2 = *.www.dominio
DNS.3 = *.dominio.int
DNS.4 = *.dominio
```

Nota: dominio -> aquí iría tu nombre de dominio en cuestión.

Ir al directorio Apache donde está el archivo openssl

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

Estando en este directorio ejecutamos los siguientes comandos para crear el certificado.

Generar clave privada

```
openssl genrsa -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key 4096
```

Generar csr

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -key C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -config C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

Crear certificado, crt

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -signkey  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -out  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\local.crt -extensions req_ext -extfile C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

Ya tienes tu certificado autofirmado creado. Espero que te sea útil y te sea de ayuda.